# Where Do Not Track Me / Blur saves its login info?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions

I'm using [Do Not Track Me / Blur](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/donottrackplus) with Firefox. It has a setting where it saves the username and login info automatically for the sites you visit (the "remember login accounts" option, see below):

[image]

When I visit certain sites while the add-on is active, it autofills the username and password fields. **I want to know where this information is stored.**

I am 100% sure it is not Firefox itself saving the information, because I cheked the browser settings and remembering passwords is disabled:

[image]

If I disable the add-on and reload the page, the fields aren't autofilled. So it has to be DNT storing the information. However, the both the "accounts" and "passwords" sections of DNT are blank:

[image]

Where can I see the saved login info on DNT?

Comment: I have contacted the official support but got no replies so far.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is "Where can I see and manage the stored passwords?", the answer is
https://dnt.abine.com/#passwords
There, the passwords are visible for me.

Perhaps you have yet another add-on?

If your question is "Where is it physically stored?" I think the answer is that it is stored locally in Blur-specific files, but potentially also, in encrypted form, on Blur's servers.